# Qt компиляция из под 64-битного Linux 32-битного приложения

Tags: qt, qt5, gcc

Имеется Qt 5.6, и UbuntuSDK. Linux x64. Нужно откомпилировать приложение в x86. Устанавливал:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9-multilib g++-4.9-multilib
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

```
/usr/include/c++/5/cstddef:44:28: fatal error: bits/c++config.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:619: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
17:03:34: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project EmailResponder (kit: 5.5.1 x86)
When executing step "Make"
```

Пока думаю как подключить.

Какие могут быть варианты решения проблемы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

надо не копипастить [ответы](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14391677/5006740) в командную строку, а подумать головой:
у тебя дефолтный компилятор версии 5 (`/usr/include/c++/5/`), а мультилиб ты ставишь 4.9

`sudo apt-get install gcc-5-multilib g++-5-multilib`

или еще проще: g++-multilib и gсс-multilib - без указания конкретной версии компилятора. поставит для дефолтной системной версии.

```
$ls /usr/include/c++/5/ | grep cstddef
cstddef
$locate c++config.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5/bits/c++config.h
```